# Putting conditional statement in class constructor

Tags: javascript, class, object

I'm trying to make a class that has an optional parameter.

Is it possible to add a conditional such as `if(!(degrees === undefined)) {this._items.degree = degrees}`

When I try to do this, I get the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" upon declaring/creating the object.

```
var element = {
    degree = 0;
}

var Radial = function(items, degrees) {
    this._items = itemsfunction(); //_items is an element structure the function makes and returns the element
    if (!(degrees===undefined)) { //where the error occurs
        for (int i = 0; i<this._items.length; i++) {
            if (!(degrees[i]===undefined)) {
                this._items[i].degree = degrees[i];
            } else {
                this._items[i].degree = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The above is my constructor

I declare it as so `radial = new Radial(item, degrees);` and `radial = new Radial(item);` and both return the same error of Unexpected identifier in the console, and the Radial object is not created. When I take out the if conditional, everything works.

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to javascript classes.

Comment: Error probably is the `=` in the object prop assignment. Should be `:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not with the conditional, it's with the line below:

```
for(int i = 0; i<this._items.length; i++){
//  ^^^
```

That needs to be `var`. Also, the object literal should be

```
… {
    degree: 0
}; //     ^^^^
```